# POST data to PHP via AJAX not working

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

I'm sending data via ajax to my server (PHP), I'm setting the call to be a POST request, but somehow it doesn't work that way and works as a GET request, here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 data: {
     user: user
 },
 url: url,
 crossDomain: true,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function (data) {
     alert(data);
 },
 error: function (error) {
     alert(error)
 }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["user"];
echo $user;
?>
```

That doesn't work, but if I change the $_POST to $_GET, it works great.

What is it that I'm doin wrong that the server intepretes GET and not POST as I want and as I'm setting it in the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

This line:

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

… causes your request to make a JSONP request. The data is send by adding a `<script>` element to the document and the response must be encoded as JSONP. Your response is not encoded as JSONP, it is a plain text response.

Remove that line.

Note that since you are using PHP, it will default to having a `text/html` content type for the response. Since you are echoing user input directly out from your script, you are vulnerable to an [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). Either encode your output as HTML (with `htmlspecialchars`) or state that you are sending plain text:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

---

This line:

```
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

…makes your HTTP request claim you are sending JSON but:

1. You aren't, you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data
2. PHP doesn't decode JSON formatted requests automatically (so it wouldn't populate `$_POST`)

Remove that line. You'll use the correct content type (because the default is correct) and PHP will populate `$_POST` (because it does does that automatically for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data).

(It works when you use a GET request because the data gets encoded in the query string instead, and the content type header is ignored because there is no content to describe the type of).

Comment: or, alternatively, encode the payload as json, which clearly makes sense.

Comment: @arkascha — Given the PHP in the question doesn't decode JSON, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Obviously you'd have to match the sides, you are right. Thought that was obvious, my fault.

Comment: Still not a good idea though. You have to write more code to encode it and more code to decode it, which is just more opportunity for something to go wrong.

Comment: But it saves you from having to take care of encoding manually, which is much more work in the end.

Comment: jQuery **already** saves you from having to take care of encoding manually. That's why the solution is to simply remove the one line I pointed out.

Comment: crossDomain just makes jQuery do all the extra stuff (like disable custom extra headers) that it does on a cross domain request when you make a non-cross domain request (include your local server redirects to a cross-origin server).

Comment: Having fixed the problems described in your original question, your new problem is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).